# Getting a node.js process to stop accepting input upon "quit" command from user

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a basic TCP client as specified in Professional Node.js.

```
//TCP Client
var net = require('net'); 
var port = 4000;
var conn;

process.stdin.resume();

(function connect() {
  conn = net.createConnection(port);

  conn.pipe(process.stdout, {end: false});
  process.stdin.pipe(conn); 

  process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    if (data.toString().trim().toLowerCase() === 'quit') {
      conn.end();
      process.stdin.pause(); 
    }
  });
}());
```

When the user enters 'quit', I want the process to end its connection to the TCP server and stop accepting input from `STDIN`.

When I do this now, I get the following error:

```
> quit
ReferenceError: quit is not defined
```

And after this, the code in my `if` statement is not run.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks to me like you're typing into a nodejs prompt or the debugger (not into stdin) and it's trying to interpret what you typed as a JS statement, rather than sending that text to your process.

Comment: I am typing into a node.js prompt, REPL.  I opened REPL and pasted in that TCP client.  `process.stdin.pipe(conn)` pipes everything I type in that prompt to `conn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REPL is already reading from stdin. You need to execute your script outside of the REPL so that there is nothing intercepting stdin except your script.

Comment: You're right.  Putting my TCP client code into a js file and calling `node <filename>` got the quit command to work.